# How to draw a rectangle within a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, draw, paintcomponent

I am attempting to draw a Rectangle within a JPanel that is within a JFrame.  I am wanting to use the paintComponents(Graphics g) method and override it but for some reason the rectangle is not appearing within the JPanel as I would hope.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class RectangleFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JPanel buttonPanel;
    JButton saveImage;
    JButton clearImage;
    JCheckBox intersections;
    JCheckBox union;
    JPanel drawingArea;



public RectangleFrame()
{
    super();
    setTitle("Rectangles");
    setSize(600,600);
    setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    intersections = new JCheckBox("Draw Intersections");
    buttonPanel.add(intersections);

    union = new JCheckBox("Draw Union");
    buttonPanel.add(union);

    saveImage = new JButton("Save Image");
    saveImage.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
    buttonPanel.add(saveImage);

    clearImage = new JButton("Clear Image");
    clearImage.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
    buttonPanel.add(clearImage);

    drawingArea = new JPanel();
    drawingArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.blue));
    this.add(drawingArea, BorderLayout.CENTER); 
}
}

      class RectanglePanel extends JPanel
{
public RectanglePanel()
{
    super();
}



@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.fillRect(25,25,100,30);       
}


}
```

Here is my main method that is in a separate class:

```
    public class SwingRectangle
{

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    RectangleFrame frame = new RectangleFrame();
    RectanglePanel panel = new RectanglePanel();
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

}
```

Comment: Where do you add your `RectanglePanel` to the frame?

Comment: I believe the method you're looking to override is paintComponent(Graphics g) (without the 's'). Make sure you then call super.paintComponent(g).

paintComponent(g) is a method on JComponent. paintComponents(g) is a method on Container.

Comment: What's up with this new trend of deleting the question after an answer has been given?  I've seen it several time recently on SO.

Answer (score 4):

You didnt add the `RectanglePanel` to your frame.

```
drawingArea = new JPanel();
```

should be

```
drawingArea = new RectanglePanel();
```

Other points:

- You still need to override `paintComponent` rather than `paintComponents` as suggested by @David so +1 to him
- The panel created in `SwingRectangle` is unused